# In-page anchors not working properly in combination with "scroll-then-fix" JS navbar code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use this nice little JavaScript to make my navigation bar (which is normally sitting 230px down from the top) stick to the top of the page once the page is scrolled down that 230 px. It then gives the "nav" element a "fixed" position.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).bind('scroll', function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 230) {
      $('nav').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 1400px;
  height: 85px;
  background-color: rgba(249, 241, 228, 1);
  margin: auto;
  border-top-left-radius: 0em;
  border-top-right-radius: 0em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2em;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  border-top: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#four">Four</a></li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Now, the problem: i have positioned the corresponding anchor targets
within the page and have given them some "padding-top" to account for the fixed navbar (about 90px), so that they don't disappear behind the bar when the page jumps to them after clicking.

```
    .anchor {
        padding-top: 90px;
        }

<a class="anchor" id="three">
```

This works fine AS LONG AS the navbar is already fixed to the top. 
But if you click on a link while the navbar is still in its original mid-page position (e.g. the first click the user will do), it just disregards the offset i gave the anchor target and jumps to a weird position where the anchor target is hidden behind the navbar (and not even aligned with the top of the page)!

If i THEN click on the link again (now in the fixed bar on top of the page), it corrects itself and displays the page as i want to. But that first click always misses - i can't figure out why! Please help

EDIT: WORKING DEMO here: http://www.myway.de/husow/problem/problem.html

Comment: Can you give us a working demo that reproduces the problem?

Comment: yes, here is a simplified recreation of the problem: http://www.myway.de/husow/problem/problem.html

Comment: In the example all the time it's behind the nav!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st Add a new class name `spacebody` to your first div with `class="space"`

```
<nav>
...
</nav>

<div class="space spacebody">
</div>
```

2nd JS use the following should fix your problem:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $(window).bind('scroll', function() {

       if ($(window).scrollTop() > 230) {
         $('nav').addClass('fixed');
         $('.spacebody').css('margin-top', '85px');
       } else {
         $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
         $('.spacebody').css('margin-top', '0px');
       }
     });
   });
```

Reason Why?

because when your nav is not fixed, it has a height of 85px, when you scroll down it has no height which is 0 height. Then everything below move up by 85px causing your to go below the target of `ONE` or `TWO` etc. It is not you are missing the first click, it is when the nav are not fixed and the click you will be scroll more down by 85px. If you scroll to top and click you will miss again.

You can easily see this if you change your CSS for `nav` with `background-color: transparent;`

With the code above should fix it when you nav become fixed to add a margin-top as 85px to the div below so they keep the same height as you clicked.

Comment: @RobinsonHuso happy to help.